# Trying to Load jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to load jQuery but I can't seem to get it to work properly.

On this page here: https://koehlerrice.com/about-3/ I'm trying to get the image to fade from one color to another on the page load. Right now to keep it simple I'm trying to go from #000 to #fff

This is where I'm at after some

Here is my css:

```
.fading-start1 
{
    background-color: #000000!important; 
    transition: background-color 3s linear!important; 
    -moz-transition: background-color 3s linear!important; 
    -o-transition: background-color 3s linear!important; 
    -webkit-transition: background-color 3s linear!important; 
}

.fading-finish1
{
    background-color: #fff!important; 
}
```

Here is my function I believe is loading jQuery

```
function avtheme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'av-about-fade', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/about-fade.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'avtheme_scripts' );
```

And, here is my JS file

```
(function( $ ) {
    'use strict';
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        if( $( '.fading-start1' ).length > 0 ) {
setTimeout( function() {
            $( '.fading-start1' ).addClass( 'fading-finish1' );
        }, 3000 );        }
    } );
} )( jQuery );
```

After a hand full of edits and help from Tony below here is where I'm at. I was able to see it working several times but it seems to be inconsistent. Like I would refresh the page, go to a new browser or incognito and it would behave differently. More often than not it's just fading for 3 seconds into #000, then another 3 seconds into #fff.

I tried different versions of your code provided below. Couple questions:

1: Does this work with RBBA? My real goal was to fade from something with an opacity of like .8 to .95.

2: Those new jQ functions you provided with the 3-second delay, are those going in the .js file or in the functions.php? I think I'm confused about what's going where. Right now I have them in the .js file.

3: Although I know 0 jQ, I tried to combine the two functions you gave me into one. Does that work like that? The one with the 3-second timer and the one that checks the length. Does that work or do they need to be separate? If so, are they both going in the .js file, functions.php or?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When enqueuing a script from a child theme, you have to use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` rather than `get_template_directory_uri()`.  The template directory is the parent theme, and the stylesheet directory is the one shared by the directory the active stylesheet is using.

In your `functions.php` file, the enqueuing would be:

```
function avtheme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'av-about-fade', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/about-fade.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'avtheme_scripts' );
```

That will enqueue the script properly for you and make it available.  Now looking at the error the console is giving for your actual jQuery - it says it can't find the variable `jquery`.  WordPress is looking for `jQuery` with the capital Q.

Here's how you can put the script together so that you don't have to replace every `$` with `jQuery` when writing your scripts.  The following block of code would go in your `about-fade.js` file.

```
(function( $ ) {
    'use strict';
    $( document ).ready( function() {
      if( $( '.fading-start1' ).length > 0 ) {
        setTimeout( function() {
            $( '.fading-start1' ).addClass( 'fading-finish1' );
        }, 3000 );
      }
    } );
    // Have never used beforeunload myself, so not sure how reliable it is.
    $( window ).on( 'beforeunload', function() {
      $( '.fading-start1' ).removeClass( 'fading-finish1' );
    } );
} )( jQuery );
```

One thing that used to bother me when I wrote a lot of jQuery was that I'd get console errors because the jQuery would try to execute on elements that weren't there.  For example, if I had and element like `<div class="fading-start1">` on the home page, but nowhere else on the site, I'd see errors telling me that it couldn't find `'.  Well obviously, because it's not there.

So what I generally do now is check to see if elements exist before I run any jQuery on them by checking for the element's 'length' and if it's greater than zero, jQuery will attempt to run something on it.  If it's length (quantity of elements with that selector) is less than 0, then it's not there.  (Length is a bit of a weird name for it, but that's what it is.)

That one extra instruction spares my sanity quite a bit.  :-)

**Addendum:**

To use opacity with your CSS you just have to add that to the transitions:

```
.fading-start1 {
    background-color: #fff!important;
    opacity: 0.65; 
    transition: background-color 3s linear, opacity 3s linear!important;
    -moz-transition: background-color 3s linear, opacity 3s linear!important;
    -o-transition: background-color 3s linear, opacity 3s linear!important;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 3s linear, opacity 3s linear!important;
}
```